# How could I add a header to a HTML page via CSS?

Tags: html, css, title, pandoc, heading

There is a script that uses Pandoc to produce a HTML representation of an input Markdown file. Assuming that the only control over the HTML representation I have is the specification of a single CSS file, how could I add a site title/header to the HTML?

For example, let's say I wanted to add some very simple heading a bit like the "ATLAS Briefings" bar at the top here, how would I do it in CSS, not in the HTML of the page?:

[image]

Comment: You can add content with css3

Comment: You _shouldn't_ add markup just by CSS. CSS is just for styling what's already there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `content` property in `::after` or `::before` pseudo-element to add additional text.

You can also position it elsewhere with `absolute` and `top`/`bottom`,`left`/`right` properties.

```
#site-title::after {
  content: "Another Title";
  /* If you need to position it, uncomment and modify the below values
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px; 
  left: 20px */
}

/* Add below rule if you need to position the additional text w.r.t to the current title */
#site-title{
  position: relative;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: The `content` property accepts a URL but [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) are fairly vague about its exact meaning.

Comment: Yes, I see. But I think OP just want to add a text here, not URL unless OP wants to clarify further.